# how to create fully typed Proxy with apply, get and set

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a proxy that can be called using apply as following

```
const proxy = new Proxy();
proxy().anything
```

and also can call their properties as following

```
const proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.anything
```

what I did so far is this

```
interface Target {
    (value: any): any;

    hello: () => void;
}

interface Handler extends ProxyHandler<Target> {
    get(target: Target, prop: keyof Target): any;
}

// @ts-ignore
const target: Target = {
    hello: () => {
        console.log("world");
    },
};

const handler: Handler = {
    apply: (target: Target, thisArg: any, argArray: any) => {
        return target.apply(thisArg, argArray);
    },
    get(target: Target, prop: keyof Target): any {
        return target[prop];
    }
};

const typeofProxy = new Proxy<Target>(target, handler);

typeofProxy("anyvalue");
typeofProxy.hello();
```

is there anyway that I can avoid using **// @ts-ignore**

Comment: note: I know the apply function won't work because it's not implemented yet. but I only want to any IDE will know that this a function first

Comment: This seems less like a question about `Proxy` objects and more like a question about type assertions.  You can write `target as Target` if you want, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wz5REm) or `const target = {...} as Target like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxDZXm).  Maybe you could [edit] the question so that it is primarily talking about "how can I avoid using `// @ts-ignore`" and not "how can I type a `Proxy`"?  Or, if it really is about typing a `Proxy` and type assertions aren't your preferred solution, could you edit the question to specify that? Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz that is a good solution for what you provide. but I manage to solve it pretty much similarly.

Comment: I don't understand "but I manage to solve it pretty much similarly". Do you mean that `//  @ts-ignore` is similar to using a type assertion?  Or do you mean that you don't need me to answer because you've figured it out yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I came up with help of Mr [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)

```
const target = (value: string) => {
    return typeof value;
};

interface Target {
    (value: string): string;

    types: string[];
}

const getter: Required<Target> = {
    types: ["string", "number", "boolean", "undefined", "object", "function"],
};

const proxy = new Proxy<Target>(target as Target, {
    apply(target, thisArg: any, argArray: any[]): any {
        return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argArray);
    },
    get(target: Target, p: string, receiver: any): any {
        return Reflect.get(getter, p, receiver);
    },
});

console.log(proxy("sss"));
console.log(proxy.types);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this to be simpler.

```js
const wrappedResult =
    <F extends (...args: any) => any, T>(target: T, func: F) =>
      (...params: Parameters<F>) => {
        const result = func.apply(target, params);
        return [result];
      };

const p = new Proxy(myTypeInstance, {
  get(target: MyType, key: keyof MyType) {
    const prop = target[key];
    return typeof prop === 'function' ? wrappedResult(target, prop) : prop;
  },
});
```